# bootstrap modal images loading on page load or not?

Tags: image, bootstrap-modal, pageload

I found a question here and the guy states that the images in his bootstrap modals load on every page load, no matter they are hidden until the modal is fired.

Since it is quite old, I wonder if this is still the case.

Does somebody knows, if one has a page with lots of modals in it and lots of images in the modals, do the images load on page load, before the modals are open to show them?

This would be quite inefficient...
If it is true, how can one make the images in modals load only AFTER the modal is opened?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Yes, the images in the modals load on page load, no matter the modals themselves are closed and hence the images not visible.
The browser treats them as one page site with images outside the view.

Anyway, the native lazy loading attribute which all the proper browsers support from 1-2 years now does the job. Too bad for Safary.